# Change axis displayed value in D3

Tags: d3.js, label, axis

I would like to change the value of the y-axis in my graph, such as, instead of displaying [0,18], it displays [-18,0].

My initial code for the axis is:

```
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .orient("left");
```

and I tried to modify it like this:

```
        var yAxisInv = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .orient("left")
                  .ticks(10)
                  .tickValues([-18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0]);
```

but it just moves down the whole axis. What I would like to do is **change the displayed values without changing the data**

In images, it looks like this:

[image] [image][image]

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you have defined `y` that you pass to `scale`?

Comment: @knolleary yes, sorry I forgot. I edited the question. `height` is just the size of the plot.

Comment: Just curious: your graphic seems rather unusual yet eye-catching. Could you provide a brief insight into the nature of your visualization and the techniques involved? Just a few keyword would be fine.

Comment: @altocumulus the background is a voronoi of data (humidity) collected at the beginning of each black segments (root segments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) function to define how you want the individual ticks to appear.

I think something like the following would work:

```
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("left");
              .tickFormat(function(d) {
                  return -18+d;
              })
```